# How to avoid having nested generic in class

Tags: c#, inheritance, class-design

I'm working on a side project, and I turned on all rules for code analysis in Visual Studio, and I got the warning notice:

> Warning   CA1006  Consider a design where '`Vote<T>.CalculateWinner(List<Vote<T>>)`' doesn't nest generic type '`List<Vote<T>>`'

And it really does point out a sore spot in my design. I have an abstract base class `Vote<T>` that contains a list of the options for running an election on type `T`.

Here is what I want to exist:

There are three types of objects, `PolicyCategory`, `Policy` and `Funding`. A `PolicyCategory` contains a list of votes on the policies within it, and a vote on a `Policy` must also contain a list of votes on a `Funding` object. The election procedure (happens to be STV) is then run on the votes in the category, and then on the votes on the winning policy. The procedure is the same for both types of votes.

What I have now is `PolicyVote : Vote<Policy>` and `FundingVote : Vote<Funding>`, the core election logic is in `Vote<T>`, and I have methods that cast `List<PolicyVote>` to `List<Vote<Policy>>`, and then call `Vote<T>.CalculateWinner()`.

This is clearly pretty horrible as I'm hacking around the lack of contravariance in C#.

How can this be made better?

Comment: I don't understand, you can't cast `List<PolicyVote>` to `List<Vote<Policy>>`, do you mean you create a copy of the list? And C# does support variance: `List<PolicyVote>` can be cast to `IEnumerable<Vote<Policy>>` or `IReadOnlyList<Vote<Policy>>`.

Comment: @svick When I say cast, I mean use a loop and cast all the members individually.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on CodeReview or StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using an interface for Vote instead of generics.

That way if you had something like:

```
interface IVote {
    // your interface requirements
}
```

And then on your class definitions implement the `IVote` interface:

```
class PolicyVote : IVote {
    // class def
}

class FundingVote : IVote { 
    // class def
}

//etc.
```

You could then avoid casting to `Vote<T>` and use `IVote` as a type instead and any class that implements `IVote` will be recognised by the compiler as type safe :

```
public static int CalculateWinner(List<IVote> votes) {
    // your calc logic
}

//You can now pass any object that implements `IVote` to the method
//assuming policyVotes and fundingVotes are type List<IVote>
CalculateWinner(policyVotes); // this will work
CalculateWinner(fundingVotes); // so will this
```

Comment: Doesn't this have the same contravariance problem?

Comment: How can I pass in a `List<PolicyVote>` and have it work?

Comment: @soandos - are you both iterating and modifying the list, or just iterating it? If the latter, you can cast the list to a more general type that doesn't allow mutation, which should then let you cast the contents to a supertype. List is  only an issue because it allows both.

Comment: @Jules I am modifying the contents of the list (the individual votes), but not the list of votes itself. So the cast `(List<IVote>)(votes)` if votes is of type `List<PolicyVote>` is safe?

Comment: As svick pointed out earlier, you can cast to IEnumerable<superclass> or IReadOnlyList<superclass> from List<subclass>, which should work for you.